# What is invalid SourceLocation in clang and how to interact with it?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to replace some variable declarations with others.

For example

```c++
int a = 5;
```

becomes

```c++
T<int> a = 5;
```

More generic

```c++
X a = _const;
```

becomes

```c++
T<X> a = _const;
```

I tried to implement an ASTVisitor descendant in clang:

```c++
bool VisitVarDecl(Decl *f) {
    if (VarDecl* VD = dyn_cast_or_null<VarDecl>(f)){
    Expr* init = VD->getInit();

    SourceRange definition = VD->getDefinition()->getSourceRange();
    FullSourceLoc exprLoc = ctx.getFullLoc(init->getLocStart());
    FullSourceLoc vLoc = ctx.getFullLoc(VD->getLocStart());
    ...
```

I want to replace the definition of variable in the next way:

```c++
TheRewriter.ReplaceText(VD->getLocStart(), exprLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber()-vLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber(), someSting);
```

But any call exprLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber() leads to segmentation fault. For example I just try to print exprLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber():

```c++
llvm::outs()<< "init start at " 
    <<exprLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber(&isValid)
    <<" is "<<(isValid?"valid ":"invalid ")
    <<", decl start at "
    <<vLoc.getSpellingColumnNumber()
    <<".\n";
```

And output is
init start at 9 is invalid , decl start at 1.
<…>
Segmentation fault

What does it mean “invalid” SourceLocation and how to interact with it?

Comment: Naively: a source location is invalid if it has not been set.

Comment: Do you accept solution in libclang (c interface)?